# Sort a counter based, re-organize based on frequency, in Python

Tags: python, data-processing

My code looks like this:

```
with open('toy_two.json', 'rb') as inpt:

    dict_hash_gas = list()
    for line in inpt:
        resource = json.loads(line)
        dict_hash_gas.append({resource['first']:resource['second']})

# Count up the values
counts = collections.Counter(v for d in dict_hash_gas for v in d.values())

# Apply a threshold
counts = {k:v for k,v in counts.iteritems() if v > 1}

print(counts)
```

Here is the data:

```
{"first":"A","second":"1","third":"2"} 
{"first":"B","second":"1","third":"2"} 
{"first":"C","second":"2","third":"2"} 
{"first":"D","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"E","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"F","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"G","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"H","second":"4","third":"2"} 
{"first":"I","second":"4","third":"2"} 
{"first":"J","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"K","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"L","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"M","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"N","second":"0","third":"2"}
```

The corresponding output:

```
{u'1': 2, u'0': 5, u'3': 4, u'4': 2}
```

What I'd like to do is sort this output, so that it's rendered as:

```
{ u'0': 5, u'3': 4, u'4': 2, u'1': 2}
```

Thus far I tried `counts = counts.most_common()`, but it didn't work. I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'most_common'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Count up the values
counts = collections.Counter(v for d in dict_hash_gas for v in d.values())
```

counts is a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instance, which understands [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method.

```
# Apply a threshold
counts = {k:v for k,v in counts.iteritems() if v > 1}
```

counts is now a `dict`, which doesn't understand `most_common`.

You just need to apply `most_common` first, and then apply the treshold:

```
data = [{"first":"A","second":"1","third":"2"} ,
    {"first":"B","second":"1","third":"2"} ,
    {"first":"C","second":"2","third":"2"} ,
    {"first":"D","second":"3","third":"2"} ,
    {"first":"E","second":"3","third":"2"} ,
    {"first":"F","second":"3","third":"2"} ,
    {"first":"G","second":"3","third":"2"} ,
    {"first":"H","second":"4","third":"2"} ,
    {"first":"I","second":"4","third":"2"} ,
    {"first":"J","second":"0","third":"2"} ,
    {"first":"K","second":"0","third":"2"} ,
    {"first":"L","second":"0","third":"2"} ,
    {"first":"M","second":"0","third":"2"} ,
    {"first":"N","second":"0","third":"2"}]

from collections import Counter
c = Counter(int(d["second"]) for d in data)
print(c)
# Counter({0: 5, 3: 4, 1: 2, 4: 2, 2: 1})
print(c.most_common())
# [(0, 5), (3, 4), (1, 2), (4, 2), (2, 1)]
print([(value, count) for value, count in c.most_common() if count > 1])
# [(0, 5), (3, 4), (1, 2), (4, 2)]
```

Comment: hmm, I see- thank you. but- now when I reorder them- I get this new error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

Comment: cool, that's a good one- I was also able to threshold it with this crazy thing `counts = [list(group) for val, group in itertools.groupby(counts, lambda x: x[1] > threshold) if val]`, but yours is cleaner

Comment: do you know what would be the best way to visualize it as a histogram/barchart?

Comment: It's simple enough, so any library should do. Matplotlib is well documented : https://matplotlib.org/